# Using a cookie as a counter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create and store a cookie with the jQuery Cookie Plugin. I want to cookie to just be an ordinary counter. I need it to be a cookie because I want to keep the counter going if the page is refreshed. When some condition is true I want, 1 to be added to the cookie value. It seems simple but I am having trouble with using the plugin.

I have created the cookie like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.cookie("cookieValue", "0", { expires: 7 , path: '/' }); 
});
```

A small example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
if (/*some condition*/) {
    cokieValue++;
}
```

That did not work when the condition was true, the cookie value remained at 0. I also tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.cookie("cookieValue", "0", { expires: 7 , path: '/' });  
    var cookieValue = parseInt($.cookie("cookieValue"));

    if (/*some condition*/) {
        cookieValue++;
    } 
});
```

This also did not work - cookieValue remained at 0. Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check to see if it exists before you update it with zero.

```
if( $.cookie('cookieValue') === null ) { 
    $.cookie( 'cookieValue', '0',  { expires: 7, path: '/' } );
}
```

You need to save the value after you update it.

```
$.cookie("cookieValue", cookieValue, { expires: 7 , path: '/' })
```

So the final code would look like

```
$(function(){  //shortcut for document.ready
    var cookieVal = $.cookie("cookieValue");  //grab the cookie
    if( cookieVal === null ) {   //see if it is null
        $.cookie( 'cookieValue', '0',  { expires: 7, path: '/' } );  //set default value
        cookieVal = 0;  //set the value to zero
    }
    var cookieValue = parseInt(cookieVal,10);  //convert it to number

    if (/*some condition*/) {
        cookieValue++;  //increment the value
        $.cookie("cookieValue", cookieValue, { expires: 7 , path: '/' }); //save new value
    } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the step by step comments, very helpful.

Comment: Is it different for firefox and chrome, in my browsers your code is not working can you attach jsfiddle example with your answer i need this functionality with js/jquery code immediately. need your help

Comment: @Anup, Oh no you need it immediately. I am betting you did not include the jQuery cookie plugin.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.cookie("cookieValue", "0", { expires: 7 , path: '/' });  
    var cookieValue = parseInt($.cookie("cookieValue"));

    if (/*some condition*/) {
        cookieValue++;
        $.cookie("cookieValue", cookieValue, { expires: 7 , path: '/' });
    } 
});
```

Gotta set the cookie with the new value.

Comment: Care to share why this was downvoted? It certainly answers his question accurately (just as the accepted answer does).

Comment: Every time the page loads, it resets the counter to zero. [I thought I left the comment, realized it is sitting there in a tab, I never hit submit]

Comment: That's true, but that is a flaw with the other part of his code. The question was about how to update the cookie value, which is what was answered here. I certainly agree that yours is a more correct answer, but I would argue that this one is not incorrect with regards to the question asked.